# Can someone explain me the Background Audio Task?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, background-audio

I'm still struggling with the Background-Audio in UWP. I already found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio), but it only explains, how it works, without any code examples. Of course there is the UWP Sample for Background Audio on Github, but its to complex and unclear, so i'm looking for someone who can expain me everything with code examples?